# How to search for TFS items that are in still in Refinement?

Tags: tfs, wiql

I am trying to create a search query to search for TFS items that are in Refinement from a TFS board and am stuck with that.

Basically I want to be able to add a badge of amount of work items that are currently being displayed in the Refinement column in our dashboard:
[image]

When I open the relevant TFS item from the Board I can see that there is a column with value as Refinement but am not able to create a search query for that column or value:
[image]

Please help me with search query column that I can use or help write a WIQL query to lookup "in refinement" items from a TFS board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Board Column" in the search:
[image]

In WIQL you can search for the same thing like this:

```
[Source].[System.BoardColumn] = 'Refinement'
```